# my [young / younger / youngest] sisters

Tags: grammar

A friend of mine has a big family.
She is a Chinese girl, and has five sisters, who are all younger than she. She wants to know how to introduce her five sisters.

To make it easy to understand, I use A, B, C, D, E to represent her sisters' names.

- A and B are twins, both are 12 years old
- C, D and E are 10, 9, 7 years old respectively.

Here is my suggestion for her:

> "Hi, this is A, and her twin sister B. C is my younger sister; she is 10. D is C's younger sister; she is 9. E is my youngest sister; she is 7."

Because English is not my native language, I am not sure whether my answer to her question is grammatically correct.

Comment: You would say 'C is my middle sister'.  I'd use "Hi, Bill. Let me introduce you to my sisters. These are my eldest sisters, A and B. They are twins. This is C, my middle sister. This is D, and my youngest sister is E."

Comment: As @Edwin implied, it will probably be SIMPLEST for your friend to introduce all of her sisters by comparing them to HERSELF. She can introduce A & B as her "eldest sisters", because they are the oldest of the four sister. She can introduce D as the youngest sister, because she is the youngest of the four sisters. Sister C is between them in age, so she can introduce C as her "middle sister".

Comment: eldest sisters? but their ages are smaller than my friend's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were introducing my siblings, I would consider that simply appearing to follow age order and winding up with "and the youngest is..." would be enough to establish age order.

> Let me introduce you to my younger sisters. A and B are twins, this is C, this is D, and my youngest sister is E.

If you're including ages, like you did in your question, nothing further needs to be explained about their age order.

> Let me introduce you to my younger sisters. A and B are twins - they are 12, this is C - she's 10, D is 9, and E is 7.

Note that there are a couple additional ways that my examples differ from yours: first, it is usual to begin introductions after a preliminary from one side, not right after "Hi". So your companion might say "Can you introduce me?" or you might say "Let me introduce you to my sisters", before embarking on the introductions. Second, "she is" is replaced with "this is", since "this" is more personal; "she" sounds like you're referring to someone across the room or on a stage, etc.

Comment: There is a convention (which your answer follows), I'm not sure how widely held, to always introduce children in age order, oldest first.  This helps you to remember other people's childrens' names - you just have to remember "Luke, Jim and Joe" and then when you see them again you can work out which is which by seeing which one's the eldest.  So, whatever you do, stick to the oldest-to-youngest order.

Answer (score 2):

Is this conversational?

... and these are my younger sisters: a, b, c, d, and e.

As to the grammar I couldn't say.  Looks ok as I read it.  But I'd say, "this is", not "she is".  I think it would come out something like this in my home town.

Hi, these are my younger sisters.  This is A and B, who are twins.  And these are C, D and E.  D is ##,  C is 9, and my youngest sister E, 7 years old.

I  think "respectively" sounds odd, but that probably is just a regional thing.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that A and b both are my eldest sisters and They are twins and both are 12 years old. C is my middle sister and her age is 11. D is my next middle sister and her age is 9. E is my younger sister and her age is 7.